# Create react app not displaying in react native WebView on android 4.4

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, create-react-app

I have a a webview that loads a create react app application. This works perfect on ios and most android devices. But when I tested on android 4.4 it shows a white screen. I have tested this with vanilla js using:

```
 <div id="test"></div>
 <script>
     document.getElementById('test').textContent = "test";
 </script>
```

This works and will display test. I have searched online and can see issues to do with the WebView and javascript but I can't find anything relating to bundled js. Has anyone come across this issue before? Any help in shining some light on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the webview code:

```
<WebView
    renderLoading={() => (
      <View style={Styles.webviewLoader}>
        <Loader />
      </View>
    )}
    onNavigationStateChange={onNavChange}
    startInLoadingState
    javaScriptEnabled
    style={Styles.webview}
    source={{ uri }}
  />
```

Comment: Could you share the code so we i have a look into it?

Comment: Sure. I have updated my question.